# Does laughing at something kufr on TV make me a kafir?

Tags: kufr

I have watched a Turkish TV show/movie that might have been talking a little bit about علمانية (secularism), however some funny things happened in this show (stuff that has nothing to do with Kufr), and I laughed at it. Do I agree with the kufr in this case or not, as I know what I did has nothing to do with Kufr.

First of all because I wasn't laughing at Kufr, and let's say I laughed at something that is Kufr I don't have to agree with it when I laugh. I searched many fatwas on Islamweb, Islamqa, and I sent questions to a few scholars, but I haven't gotten an answer yet. I always like to ask because if I didn't I keep having "waswas" (doubts).

Comment: You do not become kafir by laughing at something that is kurf or non Islamic.

Comment: yeah unless if you agree it right?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

> Whoever disbelieves in Allah after his belief... except for one who is
> forced [to renounce his religion] while his heart is secure in faith.
> But those who [willingly] open their breasts to disbelief, upon them
> is wrath from Allah , and for them is a great punishment - [Al Nahl - 106](http://corpus.quran.com/wordmorphology.jsp?location=%2816:106:15%29)

I am quite sure that you have not **opened your breast to disbelief** in this case.

However we must take care so much about our belief, because disbelief approaches us in a very hard to detect way:

> قال رسول الله (صلی الله علیه و آله و سلم): دبیب الشرک فی امتّی کدبیب النملة السوداء علیٰ الصخرة الصماء فی اللیلة الظلماء
>
> The Holy Prophet (PBUH): **Creeping of Shirk in my [Muslim] nation is infidelity more hidden than the creeping of black ant on a black rock in the pitch-darkness of the night.** [Reference](http://mashrabenaab.com/user_selected_chapter_detail.asp?mn=oyphsi63613636)

Comment: How about .. if my friend called me "magican " , ( HE was mocking me ) , then I laughed @ him is that kufr or not , and it's also important to say that I didn't agree that and I've never say to him that "Yes I am " , and he said it in a pretty funny , if you can answer in Arabic answer me because I am Arabian , I am from Jordan

Comment: @Fuadkhattab Personally I don't suppose the simple friendly conversations that are not changing our beliefs Kurf.

Answer (score 2):

While there will be strict scholars who readily declare disbelief, there's many high-level scholars who declare that intention is required for disbelief (see below).  A chuckle at the TV would not suffice unless you were intentionally mocking God's laws.

**1.** [Al-Azhar University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Azhar_University) prepared *The Response* ([pdf](http://www.fixyourdeen.com/TheResponse-EN.pdf), [URL](http://www.fixyourdeen.com/)), which states:

> Accordingly, a Muslim must not rush into making an accusation of disbelief against someone who rules against God’s laws, be it an individual, a society, or a country, until s/he has made sure that their ruling stems from disbelief, or mockery. **Such decisions are based on intentions** that are often hidden and not explicitly stated [i.e. within governments or groups] and the reasons for them are rarely announced.

**2.** In the [Open Letter to Al-Baghdadi](http://www.lettertobaghdadi.com/), a large number of scholars worldwide endorsed a document in response to ISIS leader [Al-Baghdadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Bakr_al-Baghdadi)'s behavior.  They write:

> ... **disbelief requires the intention of disbelief, and not just absentminded words or deeds**