# Is this committing kufr?

Tags: shaitan, kufr

This is in all seriousness. I'm not sure if it's from whisperings of Shaytan. I was watching a korean talk show where they discuss people's issues at home in a comedic way and I laugh along with some of what they say but I know what they do is wrong. I read somewhere that if you are "pleased" with kufr you become a kafir. Does this apply here? I've been watching korean variety shows in my leisure time but I haven't been recently because i read the hadith about zina of the eyes. So now I'm worrying if I committed many major sins. I've repented but I'm afraid I'll go back into watching those shows. There are many other thoughts that cross my mind that I believe are from Shaytan, and I keep thing I've commited kufr and that I should make ghusl and restate the Shahada. It's really getting to me I keep thinking about hell constantly, I sometimes even cry. Please give me advice. P.S. I'm a 16 yr old revert Muslimah.

Comment: Also, duplicate of [Does laughing at something kufr on TV make me a kafir?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5951/17163)

Answer (score 2):

Salaam Sister,

Don't worry ... every person makes mistakes. But the important thing to do is, to realise if you have made a mistake and to repent for that mistake. And ask Allah for his love, mercy and guidance. And inshallah Allah, who is Love himself (it is his attribute, sifat).. Allah loves you... the very fact that you are fearful and want to return to Allah is what will lead you to Allah.

No you have not become kafir... Just try to fight your naafs, your desires... And always keep trying to return to the path of Allah and you will be victorious in this world and the next !!

And also I would like to Welcome you as a brother into the Family of Islam (The Ummah)... In Islam everyone is a family !! And it is every Muslims duty to help another !

Comment: Nice Suggession...

Answer (score 1):

Every muslim should study/learn these nullifiers of islam:

1. To associate partners in worship of Allah
2. Setting up intermediaries between a person and Allah is disbelief
3. Believing that the mushrikeen (those who commit shirk) are not kaffirs, or doubting, supporting, defending and correcting the beliefs of kufar is kufr
4. To believe that the guidance of someone other than the Prophet (sws) is better or that the ruling by other than the rule of the Prophet is better is kufr.
5. Hating any ruling or anything that the Prophet sws came with despite practicing it is kufr.
6. mocking or joking any part of the deen, whether its rulings or the Prophet, or Allah and his names and attributes is kufr.
7. involvement in magic.
8. standing by the mushrikeen, supporting them aiding them against the muslims is kufr.
9. believing that some people don't have to follow the Prophet sws because their special is kufr since they deny part of the shahadah
10. completely turning away from the religion not learning it and practicing it is kufr.
11. abandoning prayers completely = apostasy

committing sins does not nullify one's islam be it major or minor.

Comment: but what is point 2 ...

Answer (score 0):

Al Salam Aleikum

No you have not committed Kufur. Allah Taala will judge us on what we do and say not some random thoughts that any Muslim can get from time to time.

If you ever get such thoughts just defeat Sheitan by saying Shahada